# Sonar Qube says Objects.inNull always evaluates to false resulting code build fail in production

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, sonarqube

For some reason sonar reports(Client reports) that the below Objects.isNull always evaluates false disabling the production upgrade. can someone help me understand why does that happen from the client sonarqube and how to fix?

```
Iterable<Sim> result = repository.findAllById(list);
        
        if (Objects.isNull(result)) {  // Sonar thinks it always evaluates to false
```

Comment: `result` may be _empty_ bot not `null`.

Comment: Since the implementation of `findAllById` returns a non-null iterable whose `iterator()` is always empty if no match for `listImsi` has been found. This is considered good practise, since you can omit the null-check, as SonarQube did correctly detect.

Comment: @Glains- Thank you,Does it mean that findAllById never returns a null reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` may be *empty* but it will not be `null` and `Objects.isNull()` will therefore never return `true`.

If no mathing data is found in the database, `hasNext()` returns `false` for every `Iterator` returned by `iterator()`.

While you are technically able to create your own implementation, it would likely not make sense to return `null`.

If you really want to do it and have a reason to, you can add a `//NOSONAR` comment explaining it in the same line and the warning will disappear.

Comment: I suppose you mean that the undelying `Iterator` is empty, not the `Iterable` (which does not have a `hasNext()` method. Also, why would there a reason for `//NOSONAR` to keep a conditional that is always `false` (as it just adds up uneccessary complexity)?

Comment: @dan1st, Thank you. So this would be a better option iterable.iterator().hasNext()?. If yes Will that won't throw NullPointerException in case iterable is null(As iterator() will be called on null reference in such case)

Comment: Yes, that is a better/working method. NPEs are no problem because it will not be null as I said.

Comment: I dont know this. Why does it never return null? Can you please provide documentation reference

Comment: @Glains yes, I messed up my explaination a bit on the first part. As for the second part, I said that a **custom implementation** 
could technically return `null` and the `NOSONAR` comment could be used in that case because the sonar issue ignores custom implementations in that case. I cannot see a reason to create such a custom implementation, however.

Comment: @Rakesh See [the sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/ba7fe5b7db9b489b7ba03b1b5abc5f3483bd9345/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.java#L39) for reference: `never null`. Also, there is no reason to return null if it can be empty. Why provide unnecessary NPE pitfalls?

Comment: For more reference here is the doc URL-https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findAllById-java.lang.Iterable-